# Design Custom Icons for IOS Tab Bar

Tags: ios, graphics, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I was wondering how to create high quality custom IOS Tab bar icons. I've been following the Apple Human Interface guidelines and have made the 30x30px images they recommend in Illustrator.

For some reason the icons with curved edges get pixilated. I believe this has to do with the transparency I have to set. On icons I made that use nothing but straight lines there are no rough edges. See the icons below.

[image]

I was wondering if anyone knew of any tutorials or had instructions for making high quality icons for the tab bar that don't get pixilated when transparencies are added. I have the entire CS6 suite so I can use any program in there.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create @2x versions of the images which are 60x60 and see how they look.